# How to display custom key icon on Terminal.app?

Tags: macos, terminal, passwords, icons, unicode

When sending a POST request to a server that requires user and password authentication, Terminal.app displays a blinking key icon which I [believe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384380/is-there-a-unicode-glyph-that-looks-like-a-key-icon) is not Unicode.

[image: Enter host password for user 'bucaran']

When asking the user to enter sensible information in my own script, I could check whether `TERM_PROGRAM` is an `Apple_Terminal`, but I don't know how to display the blinking icon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The “key” image isn't a character glyph, it's a custom cursor shape that Terminal draws.

Terminal displays this special cursor shape whenever it looks like the user is being asked to enter a password or similar sensitive data. In addition to displaying this cursor, it restricts the keyboard to Roman input methods in order to avoid having an input method inadvertently display sensitive information as inline text or in another window. This behaves like the standard OS X password text field.

Terminal enters this mode when it sees that the TTY device is configured for canonical (aka “cooked”) mode and character echo is off. In this configuration, user input isn't echoed and only the TTY device input buffer will see the characters until you type Return to send it to the application program. This ensures that neither the TTY device nor the application program are able to echo user input while you're entering the text, so this configuration is usually only used for reading sensitive information.

You can see it in action in Bash, by running

```
stty -echo && echo Tell me your secrets: && cat; stty echo
```

`stty -echo` turns off TTY character echo, and when Bash runs a command it enables canonical mode, so the following `cat` command will run in “password” mode. `cat` will echo each line of input until you type <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. `stty echo` turns it back on after `cat` exits.

Note that a shell script can simply use `read -s` to read with the TTY in this mode, e.g.,

```
while read -sp 'Tell me your secrets: '; do echo; echo $REPLY | vis; done
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: How does Terminal detect a change to the terminal parameters (cooked mode, character echo, etc.)? Is there an API for that or does it poll periodically or what?

Comment: @fumoboy007 I suggest you post that as a question.

Comment: @ChrisPage Posted: http://superuser.com/q/1143568/230880